# Найти email на странице simple html dom

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
На страницах, которые парсятся по simple html dom (список компаний), иногда встречаются email'ы. Проблема в том, что проследить структуру, и определить элемент, внутри которого они встречаются, невозможно. Они внутри текста, заключённого то в `div`, то в `p`, то вообще в `li`, причем то в начале, то в середине, то в конце текста. В общем, полный хаос. Единственное, что есть среди них общего - значок `@`. Вопрос: как их добыть? Спасибо!
P.S. Для особо щепетильных - гарантирую, что собранная база не будет использоваться для спама, а только для наполнения каталога компаний на сайте.

Comment: регуляркой по странице. Чз `file_get_content($url)` получаете html код и фигачите регуляркой. Если писать грамотно, то надо дописывать условия на несколько мыл и тд.

Comment: @VyacheslavPotseluyko вот в регулярках я и не силён((